# Selenium + chromedriver en ingles

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, test-ng

Estoy automatizando un sitio web en el cual siempre ha abierto el navegador en google chrome como español y aparece el mensaje un software automatizado de pruebas esta controlando chrome,  de un momento a otro me empezo a aparecer en ingles con el mensaje "chrome is being controlled by automated test software", por ende los nombres de menus , label y botones aparecen en ingles, mi pregunta es que determina que aparezca en español o en ingles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a tu pregunta, depende de muchos factores. Puede  haber cambiado el html de la página, por ejemplo. Eso me pasó una vez con un tracker de precios, y al final tuve que reescribir los endpoints para que apuntasen a los 'nuevos' elementos.

Pero si una cosa he aprendido, sin duda es que enlazar ítems por su nombre no es una buena idea. Si es posible, te aconsejo utilizar los identificadores de cada elemento en lugar de su nombre. Esto no siempre es posible, pero vale la pena intentarlo, ya que un nombre se puede querer cambiarlo por muchos motivos, pero un identificador ya es más raro.

Espero haberte ayudado,

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias Sergio, creo lo mismo sobre el enlazar los items por nombre, gracias.